# Sharepoint & Javascript: Handling Access Denied Error with Open In Windows Explorer. Catch Always Executing

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, error-handling, try-catch

So I am trying to handle an error when I attempt to open a file location in windows explorer from SharePoint. If the website is not in your trusted sites while in IE the browser will throw an Access is Denied error. I have this written and working but my problem is that my catch is running every time. I am assuming it's something very simple but through a good amount of research I haven't been able to figure anything out.

```
View_Click: function ($event) {

    var clickedFolder = $scope.Folders[$event.$index];

    var absoluteLibraryUrl = "file://" + location.host + "/DavWWWRoot" + _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/" + clickedFolder.Title;
    try {
        window.open(absoluteLibraryUrl);
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert("Please Add clientportals.sdcpa.com to your trusted sites, in order to use open with explorer funtionality.");
    }



}
```